# Trying to use / on Path object Python

Tags: python, file, pathlib

The program takes an optional command line argument (which is meant to be a directory path)

I am using python pathlib and shutil to move files.
Here's the code:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(sys.argv[1])

shutil.move(path / file, path / e.upper())
```

Where e is just a string representing certain file extension;

Input:

```
 python3 app.py /home/user/Desktop
```

This code generates an error:

```
'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

The / operator works fine if I don't specify the second argument in the command line (and use Path.cwd() as the path instead)

Comment: Please show the full stack trace, what you have there is not enough

Comment: The code you posted will generate `NameError`s, because `shutil`, `file` and `e` are not defined. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Note that [``shutil.move`` is not documented to take path-like arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move). Also, please post the entire traceback, not just the error message.

Comment: I simply converted the path object to string and it worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `rename` function of `Path` to move a file, if you're using the `pathlib` module.

ie.

```
(path / file).rename(path / e.upper())
```

Otherwise, if you wish to use the `shutil` module, then you must convert your paths to strings before passing them to `shutil.move()`

ie.

```
shutil.move(str(path / file), str(path / e.upper()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering file and folders path as string solved this error

```
shutil.move(str(source_path),str(destination_path))
```